# LINQ to SQL query resulting in StackOverflowException

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0, stack-overflow

The LINQ to SQL query in the function below causes a StackOverflowException during run-time. What do I need to do to resolve this? I don't think it's an infinite loop problem - I think I just need to reduce the call stack?

```
Public Shared Function AddFilters_Current(ByVal query As IQueryable(Of UserChecklistItem)) As IQueryable(Of UserChecklistItem)

    Return From r In query Where
           ((r.UserChecklist.UserId = GetUserId() AndAlso Not r.UserChecklist.DelegationUserId.HasValue) OrElse
           (r.UserChecklist.DelegationUserId.HasValue AndAlso r.UserChecklist.DelegationUserId = GetUserId())) AndAlso
           Not r.UserChecklist.Completed AndAlso
           r.UserChecklist.DateActive <= Date.Today AndAlso
           (Not r.UserChecklist.DateInactive.HasValue OrElse r.UserChecklist.DateInactive > Date.Today)
           Order By r.UserChecklistId Ascending, r.Weight Descending, r.Id Ascending
           Select r

End Function

Public Function GetUserId() As Integer
    Dim sv As Object = HttpContext.Current.Session.Item("UserId")
    If Not TypeOf sv Is Integer Then Return Nothing
    Return DirectCast(sv, Integer)
End Function
```

It took me a long time to track the cause of the issue down, and I've tried taking calls to `GetUserId` outside of query and replacing `AndAlso` with `And` and `OrElse` with `Or` with no luck.

I think I need to re-write this query with something more efficient and any advice on how to do this is very welcome.

**UPDATE**

Call Stack captured via Crash Dump analysed in Debug Diagnostic Tool (not sure if I have pasted the correct thing here):

```
NET Call Stack

Function 
DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(System.RuntimeTypeHandle, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ObjectHandleOnStack) 
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetGenericTypeDefinition(System.RuntimeTypeHandle, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ObjectHandleOnStack) 
System.RuntimeType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlTypeSystem+Sql2008Provider.From(System.Type, System.Nullable`1) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlTypeSystem+ProviderBase.From(System.Type) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlTypeSystem+ProviderBase.From(System.Object) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFactory.ValueFromObject(System.Object, System.Type, Boolean, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitConstant(System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitOrderBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlOrderType) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitThenBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlOrderType) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitThenBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlOrderType) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSelect(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitOrderBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlOrderType) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitThenBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlOrderType) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitThenBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlOrderType) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSelect(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 

... cut for brevity ...

System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitThenBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlOrderType) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitThenBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlOrderType) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSelect(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitOrderBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlOrderType) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitThenBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlOrderType) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitThenBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlOrderType) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSelect(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitOrderBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlOrderType) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitThenBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlOrderType) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitThenBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlOrderType) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSelect(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitOrderBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlOrderType) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitThenBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlOrderType) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitThenBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlOrderType) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSelect(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitAggregate(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlNodeType, System.Type) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.ConvertOuter(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlNodeAnnotations) 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) 
System.Web.Query.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable.Count(System.Linq.IQueryable) 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DynamicQueryableWrapper.Count(System.Linq.IQueryable) 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryableDataSourceView.ExecutePaging(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryContext) 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryableDataSourceView.ExecuteQuery(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryContext) 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(System.Web.UI.DataSourceSelectArguments) 
System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(System.Web.UI.DataSourceSelectArguments, System.Web.UI.DataSourceViewSelectCallback) 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnPreRender(System.EventArgs) 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean, Boolean) 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean, Boolean) 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(System.Web.HttpContext) 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext) 
ASP.dynamicdata_pagetemplates_listdetails_aspx.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext) 
System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep, Boolean ByRef) 
System.Web.HttpApplication+ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception) 
System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object) 
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest) 
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest) 
System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr, Int32) 
DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_COMtoCLR(Int32, Int32, IntPtr)
```

I must admit it looks like infinite loop - bit this is a bit beyond me atm!

**UPDATE**

Below cut-down query is still causing a StackOverflowException:

```
Return From r In query Where
       r.UserChecklist.DateActive <= Date.Today AndAlso
       (Not r.UserChecklist.DateInactive.HasValue OrElse r.UserChecklist.DateInactive > Date.Today)
       Order By r.UserChecklistId Ascending, r.Weight Descending, r.Id Ascending
       Select r
```

**UPDATE**

Tried the following query with no luck - thought it would be more efficient but still causes a StackOverflowException.

```
Dim userId As Integer = GetUserId()
Dim today As Date = Date.Today

Return From r In query Where
       If(Not r.UserChecklist.DateInactive.HasValue, True, r.UserChecklist.DateInactive > today)
       Order By r.UserChecklistId Ascending, r.Weight Descending, r.Id Ascending
       Select r
```

Comment: What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: My rule of thumb is if your predicates get more then 2 or 3 deep or complicated, write it as a stored procedure instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet stack trace pasted above thanks

Comment: @asawyer You're assuming that I have permission to do that! - I do, but a solution involving stored procedures or UDFs would be tricky in above function because there is no readily available reference to the DataContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that the current code is causing a stack overflow, but even if it weren't it couldn't work. Currently you're calling your local method from within your query: that's not going to work, as it can't be converted into SQL.

Instead, I suggest you call the method before your query, storing the result as a local variable - then use that variable where you were calling it in the query:

```
Public Shared Function AddFilters_Current(ByVal query As IQueryable(Of UserChecklistItem)) As IQueryable(Of UserChecklistItem)

    Dim userId = GetUserId()
    Return From r In query Where
       ((r.UserChecklist.UserId = userId AndAlso Not r.UserChecklist.DelegationUserId.HasValue) OrElse
       (r.UserChecklist.DelegationUserId.HasValue AndAlso r.UserChecklist.DelegationUserId = userId)) AndAlso
       Not r.UserChecklist.Completed AndAlso
       r.UserChecklist.DateActive <= Date.Today AndAlso
       (Not r.UserChecklist.DateInactive.HasValue OrElse r.UserChecklist.DateInactive > Date.Today)
       Order By r.UserChecklistId Ascending, r.Weight Descending, r.Id Ascending
       Select r

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Jon - I am clearly not doing something correctly I will try your solution, however it can't be that alone because I do this in many places and it works. I am going to try your suggestion whilst building / testing a new WHERE clause I should be able to narrow it down further as I am going to build it up bit by bit, testing as I go.

Comment: @ChrisCannon: I'm sure you really *don't* do that on a LINQ to SQL query. You can do it in LINQ to Objects, but you simply can't call arbitrary methods within a LINQ to SQL query.

Comment: Hmmm I believe you, but believe me my code works everywhere else. This code is being used by a MethodExpression as part of a QueryExtender does that change anything?

Comment: I also have `strict="false" explicit="true"` in web.config

Comment: @ChrisCannon: I've never heard of a QueryExtender before, to be honest... but you'd have to give a specific example before I could really say. Anyway, does this change work?

Comment: @ChrisCannon: That's very surprising. All of them are just scalar values, presumably? Do you know which part of it is the problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39335/discussion-between-chris-cannon-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: I don't think it's the where clause now - I think a delay in compilation caused a bit of confusion, but I can definitely rule out GetUserId because I hadn't got to that when the StackOverflowException happened.

Comment: @ChrisCannon: Have you tried extracting the `Date.Today` call to a local variable in the same way?

Comment: Yes but I will try it again.

Comment: Updated answer - still no luck!

Comment: That's very strange. I'd suggest simplifying the query one bit at a time until you can provoke it with one tiny change, e.g. using two orderings instead of one, or whatever.

Comment: Your help is very welcome Jon. Please see my answer - if anyone suggests a more efficient version of my answer I will accept it (as long as it still works).

Answer (score 0):

I made my code progressively dumber until the below worked:

```
Public Shared Function AddFilters_Current(ByVal query As IQueryable(Of UserChecklistItem)) As IQueryable(Of UserChecklistItem)

    Dim l As New List(Of UserChecklistItem)

    For Each i As UserChecklistItem In query

        If ((i.UserChecklist.UserId = GetUserId() AndAlso Not i.UserChecklist.DelegationUserId.HasValue) OrElse
           (i.UserChecklist.DelegationUserId.HasValue AndAlso i.UserChecklist.DelegationUserId = GetUserId())) AndAlso
           Not i.UserChecklist.Completed AndAlso
           i.UserChecklist.DateActive <= Date.Today AndAlso
           (Not i.UserChecklist.DateInactive.HasValue OrElse i.UserChecklist.DateInactive > Date.Today) Then

            l.Add(i)

        End If

    Next

    Return From r In l.AsQueryable Order By r.UserChecklistId Ascending, r.Weight Descending, r.Id Ascending Select r

End Function
```

The problem now is the application is a bit slow!

Comment: Yes, you really don't want to do this - and note that calling `AsQueryable` isn't helping you at all here. One thing you *could* try is pulling in all the results using the same `Where` clause as before (after applying the changes in my answer) to build a `List(Of UserChecklistItem)` and apply just the ordering afterwards. Then at least you'd have the filtering done in the database.

Comment: Oh no I've just discovered what is wrong with my code - it's really embarrassing and I would have found it earlier if I had debugged it properly i.e. going further up the call stack. I just needed to use `If Not IsPostBack Then ...` What should I do with this mess of an SO page?

Comment: Wow, I don't understand why that would cause a stack overflow, but I'm glad it's sorted. Um, possibly vote to close this yourself and edit the question to indicate what happened?